# Restore missing Ringtones, iOS 8

Tags: iphone

How do I recover and set my ringtone to the lollipop guild, a song I had already purchased?

Comment: I changed the title to make it easier for others to Google.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your phone is updated to iOS 8.1.2 - this was a known issue in 8.1.1

As you update you will get a notice about it & a link to follow to get your ringtones back.

See [Restore missing tones on your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch running iOS 8.1.1](http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht204076)